# Simple subtraction does not work

Tags: php, mysql

The scipt should subtract 1 from the primary key (auftrag_id) from a table. But somehow it's not working. The variable $preauftrag_id is not getting decreased. The type of the variable is integer. I tried several subtraction-methods, but none is working. Someone have an idea?

```
$auftrag_id = $db->insert_id;
$preauftrag_id = $auftrag_id;
$preauftrag_id--;
echo "$preauftrag_id";  // Turns out the same value as $preauftrag_id = $auftrag_id;
```

Comment: Definitely a numeric result, right? Sounds stupid, but just to be sure.

Comment: Tried `echo $preauftrag_id - 1;`?

Comment: @JMC Creative: Like you said... just to be sure

Comment: @JMC he is echoing the value-1, not changing the value and echoing it. If echo-1 works, but decrementing first doesn't, they variable may be static and unchangeable. the -- operator reassigns the value. its equivalent to $a = a-1;

Comment: Use `var_dump`.  Echo won't show you the type, so you don't know what type-cohersion's going on.  Try `var_dump($preauftrag_id, $auftrag_id)`.  Also, don't rely on de-incrementing to find primary keys, since there could be holes in the table or autoincrement is adjusted on the table (and hence the id won't be valid)

Comment: @seth: PHP doesn't support static variables in that sense (that are unchangable).  it has variables, and constants (which are accessed differently).  So that can't be the issue...

Comment: Do you correct for auto_increment? I.e. first try inserts id=10, prints 10. You add `-1` to the code, then it inserts id=11, prints 10. Add an `echo "$preauftrag_id\n";` preceding the decrement.

Comment: @ircmaxell - this is gonna be hard to read, but:
class Foo
  private static $bar;

  function __construct() {
    self::$bar = 'foobar';
  }
end

try $f = new Foo(); $f->bar = 'test'; you'll probably get a warning/error. if errors/warnings are disabled, you'll see nothing and bar will still be 'foobar'

Comment: this may be a stupid comment, but is it possible that they equal each other after the subtraction because one variable is just a reference to the other? maybe try echoing before and after the subtraction.

Comment: @seth, no, `$f->bar` will be `test`.  `$f->bar` is a member variable which is very different from `Foo::$bar`. They have very different access paths (you can't get one from the other directly).  Don't confuse them.  And a static (class) variable is mutable `Foo::$bar = 'baz'` works...

Comment: Subtracting anything from the primary key is very bad idea

Comment: @dqhendricks - that's what I'm thinking. I'm not sure what the DB class returns for ->insert_id

Comment: @ircmaxwell, can you explain to me why, when I execute the code I wrote above, that I get Fatal error: Cannot access private property Foo::$bar in /Users/sethvargo/Desktop/test/index.php on line 15. It would seem to me that you're wrong :)

Comment: @seth: You're mangling concepts here.  This is definitely off-topic for this post.  If you still want to discuss this, open a new question or join me in the PHP chat...

Comment: I think the question that is most looming on my mind is... what could possibly be the purpose of decrementing an auto increment id from mysql?  Have you considered that maybe what you are trying to do is just not good?

Comment: @ruquay - agreed. if he's trying to get the last record, you can't guarantee subtracting one will work (what if you have two concurrent connections) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another thought, if $db->insert_id returns an object, PHP variables assigned by reference.

Therefore, you've essentially assigned another way to access $auftrag_id, but you haven't taken its value:

```
$auftrag_id            $preauftrag_id
         \                  / 
          ------memory------
```

(sorry for the terrible graphics)

Therefore, decrementing $preauftrag_id would actually be decrementing the same reference as $auftrag_id, which may not be allowed because its a STATIC variable of the DB class?

Comment: That's a very distinct possibility...  Hence a `var_dump` would prove quite useful...

Comment: If this is a case, then $preauftrag_id = $auftrag_id + 0; should work nicely.

Comment: @seth.vargo agree. especially since he stated that the fact that they still equal each other after the subtraction is his way of testing if the subtraction worked.

Comment: @ircmaxell, i was going to suggest var_dump, but someone beat me to it :)

Comment: and the downvote was because? please dont downvote without a comment. its just plain rude

Comment: okay, the point is, if he's trying to do SOMETHING that's not allowed to that variable and it's an object and he has error-reporting off, he's not going to know. What code are you talking about? I didn't write any code

Comment: I have proved the variable with different methods. It's definatly integer.

Comment: It seems that @seth.vargo is right. Somehow decrementing the variable also refers back to the original, it mean it also changes it. I will try another way to build my stuff. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Crayl - great to hear. Can you please mark this answer as correct then?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the `id` of the second to last row (the one before the one that was just inserted), the only reliable way is to run a query.  Try this:

```
$query = 'SELECT id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE id < '.(int) $db->insert_id.'
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1';
```

That should fetch the id of the row prior to the one in question.

Comment: this is really risky behavior. Depending on the database engine, insertion order is not necessarily guaranteed. Perhaps two of these queries are running at the same time. @Crayl could have bad behavior and wrong references. But I'm going to upvote anyway because this is possible with certain db engines

Comment: @Seth: That's quite fair and something to consider.  However, do you know of any MySQL engines where insert order isn't maintained (relative to each other, not sequence)?

Comment: mySQL no, but Postges has some and I'm sure sqlite isn't guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

In case of, try with integer casting :

```
$auftrag_id = (int) $db->insert_id;
$preauftrag_id = $auftrag_id;
$preauftrag_id--;
echo "$preauftrag_id";  // Turns out the same value as $preauftrag_id = $auftrag_id;
```